# Sidekiq launches and mysteriously disappears when started by Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, sidekiq

I'm struggling with starting sidekiq remotely with a custom v2 capistrano task:

```
namespace :sidekiq do
  desc "Start sidekiq"
  task :start do
    run "cd #{current_path} && bundle exec sidekiq --version"
    run "cd #{current_path} && bundle exec sidekiq --environment production --daemon --config config/sidekiq.yml && echo OK"
  end
end
```

Output:

```
  * 2018-01-05 11:40:51 executing `sidekiq:start'
  * executing "cd /home/deploy/applications/xxx/current && bundle exec sidekiq --version"
    servers: ["198.58.110.211"]
    [198.58.110.211] executing command
 ** [out :: 198.58.110.211] Sidekiq 5.0.5
 ** [out :: 198.58.110.211]
    command finished in 1424ms
  * executing "cd /home/deploy/applications/xxx/current && bundle exec sidekiq --environment production --daemon --config config/sidekiq.yml && echo OK"
    servers: ["198.58.110.211"]
    [198.58.110.211] executing command
 ** [out :: 198.58.110.211] OK
    command finished in 1128ms
```

I can confirm I'm getting the environment (rbenv & bundler correctly) as the first run cmd shows. But unexpectedly the sidekiq task starts and dispersal into obliviom: 1) tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid gets initialized but the process not exists and 2) logs/sidekiq.log gets created but only with the header:

```
# Logfile created on 2018-01-05 11:34:09 -0300 by logger.rb/56438
```

- If I remove the **--daemon** switch I get the process running perfectly, but of course the capistrano deploy task never ends and when I do CTRL+C sidekiq closes.
- If I just ssh into the remote and execute the command (replacing current_path obviously) it works perfectly.
- I've tried almost everything I can imagine: not using a config.file, using RAILS_ENV instead of --environment, etc.
- As the "&& echo OK" shows, the command is not returning an error.
- Capistrano is using "/bin/bash --login -c 'cd /home/deploy/applications/microgestion/current && bundle exec sidekiq --environment production --daemon --config config/sidekiq.yml'" as far as I can tell to run the command.
- Ruby v2.3.3, Capistrano 2.15.5, Sidekiq 5.0.5, Rails 4.0.12

Comment: Do you have `set :pty, true` in your `Capfile`? [Here](https://github.com/seuros/capistrano-sidekiq/issues/23#issuecomment-44156088) is some problem related with it.

Comment: @user3309314 Yes I have **default_run_options[:pty] = true** setted.. I think you nailed it but the problem is I'm pretty sure it's there because of something.. no workarounds?

Comment: Try to use [capistrano-sidekiq gem](https://github.com/seuros/capistrano-sidekiq). Maybe it'll help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by adding **&& sleep 1** at the end as explained here: http://blog.hartshorne.net/2013/03/capistrano-nohup-and-sleep.html.

```
  desc "Start sidekiq"
  task :start do
    run "cd #{current_path} && bundle exec sidekiq --environment production --daemon --config config/sidekiq.yml && sleep 1"
  end
```

Thanks @user3309314 for pointing me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you use plain Capistrano to daemonize Sidekiq, any crash will lead to downtime.  Don't do this.  You need to use a process monitor that will restart the Sidekiq process if it dies.  Use systemd, upstart and/or Foreman as explained in the docs.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Deployment#running-your-own-process

Comment: Of course, I use monit to check that. But when deploying it's needed to restart the sidekiq process to load code updates..

Comment: Systemd and upstart are process managers.  They exist to start/stop critical services.